# ASP.NET MVC Should I bother learning webforms first?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, webforms

I'm about to foray into ASP.NET Web Development and I already know some of the very basics using Visual Web Developer and some of the implementations of Web Forms. However, instead of continuing to go down the Web Forms path and mastering VIEWSTATE and all of the ugliness that comes along with it, I've decided to go the MVC route.

At this point, I'm wondering, should I continue to learn Web Forms and then move over to MVC? Or can MVC be learned independently without knowing a thing about Web Forms? What's my best course of action?

Comment: The only thing learning webforms would do for you is to make you appreciate mvc more.

Comment: Do some reasearch, see what you might like or try both. Do whatever you feel like and stop listening to others, the best will com out of you only when you do something with passion regardless of what others say.

Comment: @PopCatalin I have done some research and I've concluded a few basic things that really make me learn towards MVC: 1. Web Forms suck. ViewState sucks. I don't like looking at it, or hearing about it. Same goes for the Page Life Cycle. 2. MVC provides a logical framework, or so it seems for a web application. It's like the difference between driving somewhere with a map or without one. 3. A lot of developers that know both Form and MVC are head over heels in love with MVC.

Comment: I would just like to briefly chime in and mention that many, if not most, of the corporate world is still updating/creating their internal applications using WebForms. A good question to consider is, how hard will it be to learn WebForms after you've already learned MVC? Just my two cents.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, don't even look at Web Forms.

MVC is modeled much closer to how HTTP actually works, which makes it much easier to work with and to build today's web applications with client side scripts. Combining Web Forms and javascript is really a pain.

MVC is also much better in that it helps getting the server side structure right. It is possible to use a model-view-presenter (or controller) separation on Web Forms too, but it has to be ducked taped on top of Web Forms.

Finally, you will have nearly no use of any WebForms knowledge when starting with MVC. It's rather the other way around, the WebForms developers I've taught MVC have to be de-brain-washed from WebForms first ;-)

Comment: It seems like it. When I first saw a picture outlining the Page Life Cycle, I think I lost a few neurons.. they exploded in pain.

Comment: Any books you would recommend for somebody starting with ASP.NET that is focused on MVC and skips out Web Forms? The books I've seen on MVC seem to already assume a base of knowledge in ASP.NET.

Comment: Use Pluralsight tutorials for that, there is a free trial you can use. http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/Find?highlight=true&searchTerm=mvc and for MVC4 : http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/mvc4-building Great tutorials, with theory and lots of code.

Comment: Corporate lan (i.e fast lan), a project that should be finished in a week and a team that lacks skills in javascript.  In this scenario, Webforms is tenfold times better than MVC and it is the usual scenario. And if i would have a team that knows javascript (and html/css/incompatibilities) then PHP is the way to go.

Answer (score 10):

While much of the excitement in the .NET community is around MVC, many of the applications out there continue to be in webforms.  If for no other reason, you should continue to learn webforms so that you can convert applications over to MVC.

I've been working on MVC since the 1.0 RC, but no matter where I have gone in my consulting work, if there is .NET you almost invariably will see webforms.  In fact I would dare say in the enterprise the majority of applications are still in webforms.

In my view MVC is a much better platform, and webforms will probably not be supported eventually (although Microsoft continues to say it will).  Still how many of us said that VB6 will go away and got burned when we find an ancient bug and have to spend days just figuring out how things work?

We're still years away from having webforms be phased out completely, and you don't want to restrict what you can and can't do because you decided MVC is the only way (your company may not want to spend the money on converting their mega-spectacular webforms app because you don't like webforms).

More knowledge never hurts, but ignorance can burn you.

Comment: The gist of what you're saying seems to focus around Web Forms still being around and knowing about them won't hurt. I agree with you. But, I suppose that goes for anything. Even if you're primarily an ASP.Net developer, knowing some PHP won't kill you. It could be a good thing. What I'm wondering is, if I'm starting out with ASP.NET, should I focus on a book/training that is oriented towards MVC, or should I learn Web Forms first? Can I learn MVC without Forms?

Comment: Yes you can learn MVC without webforms, but why do it?  And yes if you're and ASP.NET developer you should try to learn any tool that will help your career.  PHP, Rails, Node... these are all tools, and each one has it's uses.  What I'm saying is that if you want to make yourself indispensable don't box yourself into one thing and say "this is it".  I've learned that the hard way.  Just look at the #1 user on stack overflow (John Skeet), he's a Java developer for Google... and one of the top C# developers.  If he had an "MVC or Webforms" thinking he would not even have tried C#.