# Webform that includes other webforms - doesn't work

Tags: asp.net

I have a webpage that supplies a structure, in it, I include multiple files. For instance:
1. header.aspx which contains a form for logging in.
2. main.aspx that includes another form 
3. footer.aspx that includes yet another form.

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
       <title></title>
</head>
<body>

        <!--#include file="header.aspx"-->
        <!--#include file="main.aspx"-->
        <!--#include file="footer.aspx"-->

</body>
</html>
```

each sub-file has it's on .cs or .vb class page, and each file has a page directive.

I get the expected error:

> There can be only one 'page' directive.

I recognize that I address my issue from the wrong perspective. How should I re-construct the structure of my page to allow me to include multiple webforms?

alternitavely, is there (there must be), a better "righter" way to do the sort of thing I am trying to achieve, being: creating one big page that is constructed from many fragments of smaller webpages/webforms.

additionally, I don't want header.aspx to be accessible by typing in its address in the browser domain.com/header.aspx, but rather I always want it to be displayed as part of a bigger webpage.

what the way to go instead of my proven to fail method?

Thanks

p.s
I don't mind doing my own research, but I do need guidance, so, I would appreciate a full example and explanation with all the information I need, but also links to articles will be highly appreciated.

Comment: i think you would like to use asp.net Masterpages?

Comment: As you are just learning, consider learning ASP.NET MVC instead of webforms.

Comment: @efkah I started playing around with it. it seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528117/WebForms-vs-MVC) explains differences. [This post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/95212/when-to-favor-asp-net-webforms-over-mvc) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266592/asp-net-mvc-should-i-bother-learning-webforms-first) have some explanation. I went from classic ASP to Webforms and now MVC... my main site is primarily webforms mixed with MVC, but if I could start over I'd go full blown MVC. If you have no requirement for webforms, I'd recommend MVC. All your preference tho.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I am going to look over that right now! Thanks

Comment: Your sample code looks like you are coming from PHP. I have not used them, but [User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can have their own code pages and respective HTML, and be included directly into a single page. If you only need a header + footer, masterpages are pretty essential. You can also nest them for variety.

Comment: Ok, i've read about user controls and this seems to be my solution! thanks!